# Android: Horizontal scrollview issue

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I am facing layout issues while using the horizontal scrollview to scroll images with checkboxes
below is my layout

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mygallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
             >
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

i am using this scrollview in a listview which is in another layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/albumsearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
            android:id="@+id/albumdetails"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

below is the layout with my image and checkbox

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/selectedImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:checked="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

but when i am running this code in small screen devices i can see only half image, how to get full image, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: After Changing my layout with checkbox and imageview to linearlayout and used `weight` attribute

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:layout_weight="1" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/selectedImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:checked="true" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"     
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```